# Sorting data in order

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function which fetch data from Firebase. The function is:

```
private var levelsArr = [Level]()
func fetchLevels() {

    DataService.instance.levelsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        if let lvlsDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            for(_, valueLvl) in lvlsDict {

                if let lvlDict = valueLvl as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let lvlId = lvlDict["id"] as? Int, let lvlCoverImg = lvlDict["coverImage"] as? String, let lvlTitle = lvlDict["title"] as? String {
                      let level = Level(id: lvlId, coverImage: lvlCoverImg, title: lvlTitle)
                        self.levelsArr.append(level)
                        print(self.levelsArr)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        })

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
    print(self.levelsArr)
}
```

When I run the app, the console give me this :

```
[Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl0", title: "Level0")]
[Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl0", title: "Level0"), Repeat.Level(id: 2, coverImage: "lvl2", title: "Level2")]
[Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl0", title: "Level0"), Repeat.Level(id: 2, coverImage: "lvl2", title: "Level2"), Repeat.Level(id: 3, coverImage: "lvl3", title: "Level3")]
[Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl0", title: "Level0"), Repeat.Level(id: 2, coverImage: "lvl2", title: "Level2"), Repeat.Level(id: 3, coverImage: "lvl3", title: "Level3"), Repeat.Level(id: 1, coverImage: "lvl1", title: "Level1")]
```

When I print the snapshot it is well ordered but when I fetch de data and put each level in a array it is no longer ordered.

Why it is doing that and how can I get my data ordered like in the snapshot?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE**

With the following changes:

```
    func fetchLevels() {
    DataService.instance.levelsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "lvlId").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        if let lvlsDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            self.levelsArr.removeAll()
            for(_, valueLvl) in lvlsDict {

                if let lvlDict = valueLvl as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let lvlId = lvlDict["id"] as? Int, let lvlCoverImg = lvlDict["coverImage"] as? String, let lvlTitle = lvlDict["title"] as? String {
                      let level = Level(id: lvlId, coverImage: lvlCoverImg, title: lvlTitle)
                        self.levelsArr.append(level)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // Configure the cell

        let lvlCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: lvlCellId, for: indexPath) as! lvlCell

        levelsReverseArr = levelsArr.reversed()

        print(levelsReverseArr)
        lvlCell.level = levelsReverseArr[indexPath.item]



        return lvlCell
    }
```

Console result:

```
Snap (levels) {
level0 =     {
    coverImage = lvl1;
    id = 0;
    title = Level1;
};
level1 =     {
    coverImage = lvl2;
    id = 1;
    title = Level2;
};
level2 =     {
    coverImage = lvl3;
    id = 2;
    title = Level3;
};

[Repeat.Level(id: 1, coverImage: "lvl1", title: "Level1"), Repeat.Level(id: 3, coverImage: "lvl3", title: "Level3"), Repeat.Level(id: 2, coverImage: "lvl2", title: "Level2"), Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl0", title: "Level0")]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why Firebase likes to 'mess around' with array's, so I cannot answer that side of your question, but to fix the issue you could use `.queryOrdered(byChild:)` to order the snapshots, changing 'id' to anything that could order your objects:

```
DataService.instance.levelsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "id").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

You may also need to reverse the array once it is full or updated...

UPDATE:

This hopefully should 'sort' your issue, if you get my pun, that is if level id is an int and you want it to be ordered for lvl 0...100? and now no need to `.queryOrdered`

```
func insertionSort<T>(_ arr: [T], _ isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool) -> [T] {
    guard arr.count > 1 else { return arr }

    var b = arr
    for i in 1..<b.count {
        var y = i
        let temp = b[y]
        while y > 0 && isOrderedBefore(temp, b[y - 1]) {
            b[y] = b[y - 1]
            y -= 1
        }
        b[y] = temp
    }
    return b
}
```

All you need to do would be change

```
levelsReverseArr = levelsArr.reversed()
```

to

```
sortedLevelArr = insertionSort(levelArr) { $0.id < $1.id }
```

Comment: I edited the question with the result of your changes. Seems not working or did I made a mistake ?

Comment: It seems it should work, I have used that code just this morning, try changing the byChild input to one of the others on the database to check, I usually use a timetstamp and that works 10/10

Comment: that is no sense my head is burning

Comment: Only thing I could suggest is trying some fake data like a time stamp in the database to test any changes to the array? Or printing the 'snapshot' to see how it's been ordered to see if the query is working

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data this shows the different query options

Comment: snapshot added in the question. When you use timestamp in you project, it is an int or a string ?

Comment: It is stored as an int, looking at your snapshot it should be entered into your array fine, try removing the .queryOrdered and keeping the reverse

Comment: exact same result for the snapshot and [Repeat.Level(id: 0, coverImage: "lvl1", title: "Level1"), Repeat.Level(id: 2, coverImage: "lvl3", title: "Level3"), Repeat.Level(id: 1, coverImage: "lvl2", title: "Level2")] when the .queryOrdered is removed

Comment: Updated the answer to include a custom insertion sort algorithm to sort your Level array out, tested it on an army with 10 Level elements with numbers from 0-100 and it worked every time, hopefully that helps

Comment: Ty for this function it works fine with it. I tried queryOrderByChild with an other id in another project and it worked perfectly. I will try to ask the Firebase support about it and will update the post with the answer if anyone wants to know what it was. Ty